# How I can directly deploy ARM template as solution template in Azure marketplace

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, solution, azure-rm-template

I have written code for ARM template which I've customized the parameters and installed the application on the server.
Now I wanted to Deploy this in the Azure marketplace as solution template what I need to do.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "adminUsername": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "adminPassword": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "envPrefixName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Prefix for the environment (2-5 characters)"
            },
            "defaultValue": "cust1",
            "minLength": 2,
            "maxLength": 11
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "scriptURL": " https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rt7055/simpledevbox1/master/simpledevbox.ps1 ",
        "VMname": "[parameters('envprefixName')]",
        "storageAccountName": "[concat(uniqueString(resourceGroup().id),'storageaccountkatalyst')]",
        "virtualNetworkName": "MyVNET",
        "vnetAddressRange": "10.0.0.0/16",
        "subnetAddressRange": "10.0.0.0/24",
        "subnetName": "Subnet",
        "subnetRef": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', variables('virtualNetworkName'), variables('subnetName'))]",
        "imagePublisher": "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
        "imageOffer": "WindowsServer",
        "imageSku": "2012-R2-Datacenter",
        "publicIPAddressName": "mypublicIP",
        "nicName": "myVMnic"

    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
            "name": "[variables('storageAccountName')]",
            "apiversion": "2015-06-15",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "tags": {
                "displayName": "[variables('storageAccountName')]"
            },
            "properties": {
                "accountType": "Standard_LRS"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
            "name": "[variables('publicIPAddressName')]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "apiVersion": "2018-10-01",
            "properties": {
                "publicIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic"
            }
        },
        {
            "apiversion": "2017-06-01",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
            "name": "[variables('virtualNetworkName')]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "tags": {
                "displayname": "Virtual Networks"
            },
            "properties": {
                "addressSpace": {
                    "addressPrefixes": [
                        "[variables('vnetAddressRange')]"
                    ]
                },
                "subnets": [
                    {
                        "name": "[variables('subnetName')]",
                        "properties": {
                            "addressPrefix": "[variables('subnetAddressRange')]"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "2017-06-01",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
            "name": "[variables('nicName')]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/', variables('publicIPAddressName'))]",
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', variables('virtualNetworkName'))]"
            ],
            "tags": {
                "displayname": " Server Network Interface"
            },
            "properties": {
                "ipConfigurations": [
                    {
                        "name": "Ipconfig1",
                        "properties": {
                            "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
                            "publicIPAddress": {
                                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', variables('publicIPAddressName'))]"
                            },
                            "subnet": {
                                "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "2017-03-30",
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
            "name": "[parameters('envprefixName')]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/',variables('storageAccountName'))]",
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/',variables('nicName'))]"
            ],
            "tags": {
                "displayname": "My Virtual Machine"
            },
            "properties": {
                "hardwareProfile": {
                    "vmSize": "Standard_A1"
                },
                "osProfile": {
                    "computerName": "[variables('VMname')]",
                    "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
                    "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPassword')]"
                },
                "storageProfile": {
                    "imageReference": {
                        "publisher": "[variables('imagePublisher')]",
                        "offer": "[variables('imageOffer')]",
                        "sku": "[variables('imageSku')]",
                        "version": "latest"
                    },
                    "osDisk": {
                        "createOption": "FromImage"
                    }
                },
                "networkProfile": {
                    "networkInterfaces": [
                        {
                            "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces',variables('nicName'))]"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "diagnosticsProfile": {
                    "bootDiagnostics": {
                        "enabled": true,
                        "storageUri": "[concat('http://',variables('storageAccountName'),'.blob.core.windows.net')]"
                    }
                }
            },
            "resources": [
                {
                    "apiVersion": "2017-03-30",
                    "type": "extensions",
                    "name": "config-app",
                    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/',variables('VMname'))]"
                    ],
                    "tags": {
                        "displayName": "config-app"
                    },
                    "properties": {
                        "publisher": "Microsoft.Compute",
                        "type": "CustomScriptExtension",
                        "typeHandlerVersion": "1.9",
                        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
                        "settings": {
                            "fileUris": [
                                "[variables('scriptURL')]"
                            ]
                        },
                        "protectedSettings": {
                            "commandToExecute": "[concat('powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File ', './simpledevbox.ps1')]"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to build a solution template for this or let me know how I can place this to the azure marketplace.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/marketplace/marketplace-publishers-guide this is too broad. read the docs

Comment: What is other option if that's not possible

Comment: how i can captured sysprep image to .vhd file do you know the template or commands?

Answer (score 1):

The marketplace is designed for Microsoft and Partners to deploy certified solutions to all Azure customers world-wide.  Directions for publishing to the market place can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/marketplace/marketplace-publishers-guide).

If you are looking to store a template just for your organization, you can save it to the portal.  Directions can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-deploy-portal#deploy-resources-from-a-template-saved-to-your-account).

Comment: Means if I don't have microsoft partners ID i cannot directly publish to microsoft so I need to create .vhd file and then publish it to marketplace

Comment: If you want to use the marketplace I encourage you to reach out to our Go-to-market (GTM) team.  https://partner.microsoft.com/en-US/reach-customers/gtm